# scrape a data from a gtag function in a script tag using scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy, tags

I am scraping a website, its script tag contains the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          
          gtag('set', 'content_group1', 'World');
          gtag('set', 'content_group2', 'AFP');
          gtag('config', 'UA-40396753-1', {
            'custom_map': {"dimension6":"Id","dimension1":"Category","dimension3":"Author","dimension5":"PublishedDate"}
          });              
          gtag('event', 'custom', {"Id":"news\/1696246","Category":"World","Categories":"World","Author":"AFP-119","Authors":"AFP","PublishedDate":"2022-06-23 07:08:42"});
</script>
```

I need to scrape the value `"PublishedDate":"2022-06-23 07:08:42"`
How can I do that using scrapy
This is what I tried:

```
time = response.xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript"]/text()').re(r"gtag\('event', 'custom', ({.*})\);")
json_data = json.loads(time, strict=False)


print('dawn time::', json_data['PublishedDate'])
```

But, I am not getting any result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this simply by:

```
time = response.xpath('//meta[@property="article:published_time"]/@content')[0].extract()
```

as there was a relevant meta tag to the field I required

Answer (score 0):

Get that data from the selector with [regex](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions), and use `json.loads()`.

```py
import scrapy
import json


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"

    start_urls = ['file:///PathToFile/temp.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        all_data = response.xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript"]/text()').re(r"gtag\('event', 'custom', ({.*})\);")
        for data in all_data:
            data = json.loads(data)
            yield {'PublishedDate': data['PublishedDate']}
```

Output:

```py
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///PathToFile/temp.html>
{'PublishedDate': '2022-06-23 07:08:42'}
```

Comment: I followed your suggested answer, however that did not work for me, I have edited the question showing the code which you suggested. Have a look at it please

Comment: `.re()` will give you a list, either use a `for loop` or `json_data[0]['PublishedDate']` (after you check that it's not an empty list). If it's still doesn't work then update me.

Comment: No, this didnt work as well. Can you tell me that `re` is regular expression, right? How can this work on something that hasn't been extracted yet. I tried extracting the text first and then applied `re.compile(...)` to search for the specific string. But it didn't work

Comment: You can read about it [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html?highlight=regexp#regular-expressions). Can you post the url so I can check it myself?

Comment: this is the [link](https://www.dawn.com/news/1696422/how-crypto-thrives-in-crisis-zones)